# Virtual Host ( Virtual Host throws domain name not found error , if we call it from other computer )

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, remote-server

I would like to host two web application into single server but I am not having domain name instead I have IP Address, and it is an Remote Server.

I use LAMP and have created two Virtual Hosts for two separate web application and have enabled that also. Suppose if my Server IP is `192.168.XXX.XXX` , then

My first Virtual host and Second one is same as first but project name will be changed

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@myfirstproject
ServerName 192.168.xxx.xxx.myfirstproject
ServerAlias 192.168.XXX.XXX
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfirstproject/public
<Directory "/var/www/html/myfirstproject/public"> 
AllowOverride all 
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "mypath"
CustomLog "mypath"
</VirtualHost>
```

If I call with `192.168.XXX.XXX.myfirstproject/` in browser it shows `Domain not found error`, but I did the same process in my local machine and it worked fine. Why its not working if we call from other computer ( Except locally ) and this is my `/etc/hosts/` file content.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.XXX.XXX 192.168.xxx.xxx.myfirstproject
192.168.XXX.XXX 192.168.xxx.xxx.mysecondproject
```

Can you please help me where I am going wrong?

What my expected output is: If I type `192.168.xxx.xxx.myfirstproject` in browser it will load the content for `myfirstproject` and `192.168.xxx.xxx.mysecondproject` in browser it will load the content for `mysecondproject`. Its working locally, but if i access it from other computer it won't work, that was my problem.

Comment: Are both the computers in the same network? Is the hosts file defined same in both the computers? Are you able to ping to `192.168.xxx.xxx.myfirstproject` from other computer?

Comment: Thank you for you reply Nimesh. Yes both the computer are connected in same network.We have a local server , in that server we have configured LAMP , If i accessed my web application from the Computer that i have configured LAMP its work well, but from other computer it wont work.Why i have to define the Hosts file in both computer , nearly n number of user can access the local server.

Comment: HOSTS file is an alternative to DNS, so it's required on all those (client) systems from where you are trying to access the application using `192.168.XXX.XXX.myfirstproject`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nimesh. Still i am not cleared , I have a Remote Server having IP address only not any domain , its possible to host more than one web application in it ( Remote Server ) , if so then how can i access it from globally, by using Virtual Host

Comment: Instead of remote server, let's name the 2 systems differently. The system that is hosting the LAMP should be called SERVER, and the system from where you are trying to access the web application will be called CLIENT. So in order to connect to `192.168.XXX.XXX.myfirstproject` from Client, the client should be aware that `192.168.XXX.XXX.myfirstproject` maps to IP `192.168.xxx.xxx`. This can be done by either publishing this information on DNS server or the HOSTS file on client system. So, is the HOSTS file updated with this mapping on CLIENT system?

Comment: How we publishing the information in DNS server , can you please elaborate me or giving any examples, because i am newbie to Server Side.

Comment: DNS is a whole different topic, you can google to know the basics. If you are using this within few systems, DNS might even not be required and HOSTS file will be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I got the solution by using .htaccess , now if i type 192.168.xxx.xxx/firstproject , then it will redirect to first project and for second project 192.168.xxx.xxx/secondproject both project are in separate directory.